# Final topology of $\mathbb R^\infty$ with respect to $\mathbb R^n$/ weak topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm stuck on this example in Boto v. Querenburgs "Mengentheoretische Topologie" and I would really appreciate some insight from our more topologically savvy friends on here. =)

Let $I$ be an ordered set, and let $(X_j, \mathcal T_j)_{j \in I}$ be a family of topological spaces, such that for $j<k$, $j,k \in I$ we have:

$$X_j \subset X_k, \quad \mathcal T_j = \mathcal T_k|X_j$$

i.e. the topology on $X_j$ is induced by the injection $i_{jk}: X_j \hookrightarrow X_k$ from the topology on $X_k$.

On $X = \bigcup_{j\in I} X_j$ let $\mathcal T \; $  be the final topology with respect to $(i_j: X_j \hookrightarrow X)_{j\in I}$; This is called the weak topology on $X$.

Example: Let $X_n = \mathbb R^n$, and let $X = \mathbb R^\infty$.
Then a sequence $(x_k = (x_{k1}, x_{k2}, \dots ))_{k\in \mathbb N}$ converges to $x = (x_1, x_2, \dots )$ iff for any fixed $n$ the sequence $(x_{kn})_{k \in \mathbb N}$ converges to $x_n$.

---

Now I don't see why the last statement should be true.

First off: To get a feel for this new kind of topology, I tried comparing it to other topologies on $\mathbb R^\infty$ known to me (and I think in the following already I must be making a mistake...)

Suppose $U = \prod_{n \in \mathbb N} U_n$ is open in the box topology on $\mathbb R^\infty$, i.e. $U_n \subset \mathbb R$ is open for all $n$. Then I think $U$ is also open in the weak topology: (I suppose $\mathbb R^j$ should be identified with $\mathbb R^j \times 0 \times 0 \times \dots \subset \mathbb R^\infty$, right?)

But then $i_j^{-1}(U) = \emptyset$ if $0 \notin U_n$ for some $n>j$ and $i_j^{-1}(U) = U_1 \times \dots \times U_j$ otherwise. Both of which are open in $\mathbb R^j$, thus $U$ should be open in the final topology w.r.t. the inclusions $i_j$.

Now consider the sequence

$$x_j = \underset{\text{j-th component}}{(0, \dots, 0,\underbrace{1}, 0, 0, \dots)}$$

Clearly $x_j$ converges to $(0, 0,\dots)$ componentwise, but $x_j$ does not converge in the box topology, hence neither in the *finer* topology introduced in the example (the weak topology).

---

So where is the above argument wrong? What am I not understanding correctly about this topology?

Many, many thanks in advance for any useful comments and answers.

Regards,

S.L.

Comment: Why is the box topology coarser than the weak topology? Isn't the weak topology the coarsest topology which endows the spaces with the induced topology based on the inclusions (not the finest topology that makes the inclusions continuous)?

Comment: @Arturo: If my argument above were correct, it would show that any set open in the box topology is also open in the weak topology, hence the weak topology would have to be finer than the box topology. To your second remark: I only have the definition given above at hand. But are the two possibilities necessarily contradictory?

Comment: @S.L. The two notions may yield different topologies: the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ makes all inclusions $i_n\colon\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ that you have defined continuous, and gives $\mathbb{R}^n$ the induced topology; so does the box topology. If you are looking for the coarsest topology that induces the topologies via the inclusions, then it will be coarser than the product topology; if you are looking for the finest topology that makes all inclusions continuous, then it would be finer than the box topology. So clearly, the two notions are not equivalent.

Comment: @S.L. Of course, the two notions may agree on some families: if the family has a maximum element, then both topologies (coarsest making all topologies induced by the inclusions, and finest making all inclusions continuous) would be the topology of the maximum.

Comment: @Arturo: Yes, you are right. And then with the definition as given (which is a one-to-one translation from the German text in front of me), you don't think there is necessarily something wrong with the argument above? (The example given in the book including the remark about convergent series then would have to be wrong with the definitions stated?)

Comment: @S.L. The problem is that I'm not sure which of the two they mean when they say "final topology with respect to the inclusions". It they mean the direct limit topology (finest topology making all structure maps continuous), then you'd be correct. But the definitions of "weak topology" that I'm familiar with usually invoke the initial topology, which would mean they want the coarsest that induces the topologies via the inclusions. So that's why *I'm* confused.

Comment: @Arturo: It is actually only one example of many, so there might be a mistake in either the definition or the concrete example (the topology is not used later and only defined to illustrate the notion of a "final topolgy"). I think I'll move on then. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that the weak topology would be the *smallest* topology which induces the given topologies on $\mathbb R^n.$ Therefore since the product topology (with basis of the form $U_1\times\cdots\times U_n\times \mathbb R\times\mathbb R\times\cdots$) also induces the standard topology on the subspaces $\mathbb R^n$, it follows that the weak topology is at least as small as the product topology. Indeed, it is exactly the product topology in this case.

Comment: @Jim Conant: Doesn't the box topology also induce the same topology on the subspaces $\mathbb R^n$? It seems to me that this is the case, since any open set in the box topology whose intersection with $\mathbb R^n$ is nontrivial restricts to an open set of the form $U_1 \times \dots \times U_n$ on $\mathbb R^n$..?

Comment: Yes, but it is not the smallest (coarsest) such topology to do so.

Comment: I agree with everything you say, but then you are implying the author simply gave the wrong definition of weak topology?

Comment: @ S.L.: are you quoting him verbatim? As you can see, defining the topology to be consistent with the topologies on the $X_j$ spaces is not well-defined, since there is more than one such topology. To get a well-definition, you have to do something like taking the coarsest such topology.

Comment: I'm not really quoting him since it is in German :) , but the translation should be quite exact. His definition *is* well-defined, though: The final topology with respect to $(i_j: X_j \to X)_{j\in I}$ is exactly the finest topology, such that all inclusions $i_j$ are continuous. Which seems to be at the exact opposite end of the spectrum for a topology restricting nicely to the subspaces $X_j$ from what you and Arturo proposed.

Comment: @S.L.: If it is the finest such topology, as you say, then the statement is simply wrong.

Comment: @S.L.: now that I think about it, the weak topology is normally defined as the finest topology which is consistent with the topologies on the smaller spaces. (E.g. this is how it's defined for CW complexes.) Perhaps there really is a mistake in the book.

Comment: @Jim: O.k., I think I'll move on then. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation in which some mildly categorical ideas are usefully clarifying, I think. Specifically, (in effect taking up a bit more aggressively some points already made in comments), the "inductive limit" or "colimit" of an ascending union of topological spaces (with continuous inclusions, of course, or things would be perverse) is (as they say in categorical situations) "unique up to unique isomorphism". One virtue of this is that there is no mandate to give a *construction*. The only possible issue (which is now-and-then delicate) is *existence*.

For locally convex topological vector spaces, it's not hard to prove that arbitrary colimits exist, including these ascending unions.

The usual *construction* exhibits colimits as quotients of coproducts (dually to the way (projective) limits are often subobjects of products). An interesting point is that in the category of locally convex t.v.s.'s, the coproduct (exercise-provably) has the *diamond* topology. This is subtly (and not to-me intuitively) different from the box topology. Certainly it is not the *product* topology, which is quite weak.

Perhaps some mild categorical considerations explain why some of the possible worries/questions here may be not-to-the-point.